# Performing a Fisher test when the odds of the events not occurring are known to be very low when compared to the events occurring

Tags: contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

Let's say I have a contingency table like this:

```
                event a present    event a absent

event b present        40               56
event b absent         23               238923
```

For my specific data, I know in nature that the probability of a and b occurring is low, then the possibility event a and b are both absent is super large.
In my opinion this could overestimate the result of co-occurrence. I'm interested in seeing when do a and b occur together more often than expected.

Is there any way to account for this? Like looking for co-occurrence of a and b but knowing that occurrence of a or b is very unlikely.

In the end I'm interested in seeing if there is a significant difference between a and b present vs only a or only b present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fisher's exact test makes no assumptions about the relative frequency of present vs absent, so having the high absence proportion does not contradict the assumptions of the test and therefore no adjustment is necessary. It is simply not true that the test will "overestimate the result of co-occurrence".

It is quite obvious just by eyeballing your data that the null hypothesis of independence is not compatible with the data. Getting 40 cases where both "a" and "b"? are present, given the very small overall presence rate for both, would be astronomically unlikely if "a" and "b" were independent.
Any of the standard contingency table tests for independence, including Fisher's test, will confirm this.

The data you show has $40+56+23+238923=239042$ cases in total.
Event "a" occurs at rate $(40+23)/239042=0.00026$, in other words, 1 in 3794.
Event "b" occurs at rate $(40+56)/239042=0.0004$, in other words, 1 in 2490.
If events "a" and "b" were independent, then the expected number of co-occurrences would be: $239042/3794/2490 = 0.025$.
You'd expect less than 1 co-occurrence!
But you actually have 40!
Much more than expected!
Highly significant!
It is exactly this sort of calculation that Fisher's test will do for you.
The fact that "a" and "b" both occur at low rates causes no difficulties. It is the number of co-occurrences vs what would be expected that is important, not the absolute size of the proportions.

What would be a problem would be if the 239042 cases were not statistically independent.
You haven't given us any background regarding where the numbers are from, so I have to assume that the data has been collected in a valid way.
If you were a scientific collaborator of mine, however, I would be pressing you to explain how the data was collected and to assure me that the 239042 cases were in fact independent.

Comment: This is not really my true data but an example. I do have a super large number of "not a, not b" cases. Do you know any other tests that I could apply? My main aim is to test whether co-mutations occur more often than expected.

Comment: How about the odds ratio? wouldn't that be impacted a lot by the very low presence rate for both? Like I imagine "not a, not b" doing most of the weighting in the OR.

Comment: @Caterina You are imagining problems that do not exist. There is no problem in conducting Fisher's test. There is no problem in computing an odds ratio, although Fisher's test doesn't even require that.